# Dealing with hyphens in css-style when writing them as style objects in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a css style such as this:

```
.AdvancedSearchGrid {
    width: 70%; 
    margin: auto;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to write those parts that start with a hyphen ie (-webkit-flex, -moz-box, -ms-flexbox, -webkit-flex) in the format they should be written in JSX, where we're supposed to use CamelCase. For example

`list-style: none` would be `listStyle: 'none',`

but how should I type those lines I mentioned, in the JSX-way?

I don't even know what to call those, so it's hard to Google for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 different problems here:

1- For `-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;`, you can simply use `WebkitFlexFlow: 'row wrap'` as stated in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

2- For

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
```

You might have to use a library as auto prefixing is not supported by React:

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36523676/1595699)