# React - Linear Gradient Inline Style vendor prefixes

Tags: reactjs, vendor-prefix

How can I do use linear gradient vendor prefixes in react? 
Is possible to do this without using any external package?

This doesn't work because an object can't have keys with same name so no style is applied to the div.

I can't use classes because I will use component variables inside this code.

```
      const sizeBackground = {
        background: `-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #fff 50%)`,
        background: `-moz-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #fff 50%)`,
        background: `-ms-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #fff 50%)`,
        background: `linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #fff 50%)`,
      }    

<div style={sizeBackground} >
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add multiple browser specific values into a CSS style in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522413/how-do-you-add-multiple-browser-specific-values-into-a-css-style-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

you need keep all in one sentence as all parameter of `background:`.
After you need add the style to the DOM, in this case `div`. so add `style={{background: _valueOfBackground_}}`.  takaking advantage of this valueOfBackground can be a variable you can put `sizeBackground;`

```
  const sizeBackground =
     `-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #fff 50%)
     -moz-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #fff 50%)
     -ms-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #fff 50%)
     linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #fff 50%)`    

<div style={{background:sizeBackground}}>
```

Comment: check the styles, because i dont know if background can have that value

Comment: if I use  const sizeBackground =
     `-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #fff 50%) with just one value it works, if I add more, style is not applied

Comment: @MMrj check this https://github.com/rofrischmann/inline-style-prefixer to use all inlines things. yes i see that, i test with the browser and try to put all sentences and i cant, so check the lib